# JQ var as .attr

Tags: jquery, variables, attr

I know it is something minor here...
Could somebody please quickly help me to write or insert this `var` so I don't have to write out the full string over & over?

```
var     edit    = $('#btn_edit');
var     disabled= '({href:"#",title: "No items checked"})';

edit.attr.disabled;
```

Note: this worked when it was written out full as below:

```
var edit    = $('#btn_edit');

edit.attr({href:"#",title: "No items checked"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the variable as parameter to `.attr()`. and as you are setting multiple attribute, you should be passing json object as parameter instead of string:

```
  var edit    = $('#btn_edit');
  var disabled= {'href':"#",'title': "No items checked"};
  edit.attr(disabled);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6v5xj55/)**

Comment: Belay my last...I'd originally tried it this way, however I'd removed the ()'s in `edit.attr(disabled)` when I'd added them to the `var` `'({href:"#",title: "No items checked"})'`. Not working yet:(

Comment: @cpardon no need in `''` and `()` in `disabled`, just create an object as `var disabled = {href: "#",title: "No items checked"};`

Comment: @Cheery I had it this way before. Should I keep `edit.attr.disabled;` or `edit.attr(disabled);`?

Comment: @cpardon `.attr()` is a jQuery function, so it should be used as a function with arguments. Pure js functions are `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`, but they work only with one attribute at a time.

Comment: @Cheery: you would also need to change the parameter value.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar what do you mean?

Comment: @Cheery Nice work. Milind had provided the right answer for correcting the function, however your explanation lead me to find the working var solution.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Are you writing about `'href'` and so on? quotes are not required in this simple case. They will be need quotes in case of the attribute's name that has spaces and other special things.

Comment: @Cheery: first thing creating as a json object as you have already mentioned and the properties need quotes around them as well as the values.

Comment: @Cheery I understand what you were saying about pure js, yet see Chris Hope's post **[Set multiple attributes at once with jQuery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-set-multiple-attributes/)**

Comment: @MilindAnantwar `the properties need quotes around them` again, not in this simple case. http://jsfiddle.net/kcv83dgv/ The quotes will be needed in case of `'href-2'` and so on.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks for providing the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6v5xj55/). Was fun to follow the battle of intellects with Cheery. Educational nonetheless :)